# Is it possible to check if user enable or disable biometric for each flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, authentication, hybrid-mobile-app, appsettings

```
List<BiometricType> availableBiometrics = await localAuthen.getAvailableBiometrics();
if (availableBiometrics.contains(BiometricType.face)) {
} else if (availableBiometrics.contains(BiometricType.fingerprint)) {
} else if (availableBiometrics.contains("weak") ||
availableBiometrics.contains("strong")) {
} else {
AppSettings.openAppSettings();
}
```

I want to know if it is possible to check  user's turn<sup>-</sup>on biometrics or off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check enable or disable biometric for each flutter app using this below function:

```
final auth = LocalAuthentication();
    checkBioMetricAuth() async {
      bool canCheckBiometrics = await auth.canCheckBiometrics;
      print(canCheckBiometrics);
    }
```

I hope it's help you..
Happy Coding :}

Comment: But this will return false if it doesn't have face id capability. Is there a way to know that the device has face-id but is disabled?